# Conjunction of separable verbs?

Tags: grammar, verb, conjunction

One can use a conjunction like *und* to link two (or more) verbs, as in *Ich lese und schreibe*, but what happens when one or more of the verbs is separable?

For the sake of concreteness, here's an example: how would one use *aufbauen* and *abbauen* in a sentence meaning something like *I build and dismantle the apparatus every day*?

Comment: _Ich baue den Apparat jeden Tag auf und ab._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In such cases you connect only the prefixes with *und* and you won't repeat *bauen*:

> Ich baue das Gerät jeden Tag auf und ab.

If you, however, connect two verbs that don't share the same root you hardly can connect those verbs close to each other. You need to split both parts:

> Ich baue das Gerät jeden Tag auf und räume es auch wieder weg.
>
> Jeden Tag baue ich das Gerät auf und räume es auch wieder weg.

Without any objects in the sentence this verbs are again close to each other:

> Ich baue auf und räume weg.

This is the same as your introducing example with *lesen* and *schreiben*.

Answer (score 0):

As an example: Ich lese, schreibe und hoere zu. Ich schreibe und hoere zu. Ich schreibe (es) auf und hoere zu. The original prefix of the compound verb will be separated as usual and put at its usual position - behind the verb.